# How to convert RowData into Row when using DynamicTableSink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a question regarding the new sourceSinks interface in Flink. I currently implement a new custom DynamicTableSinkFactory, DynamicTableSink, SinkFunction and OutputFormat. I use the JDBC Connector as an example and I use Scala.

All data that is fed into the sink has the type Row. So the OutputFormat serialisation is based on the Row Interface:

```
override def writeRecord(record: Row): Unit = {...}
```

As stated in the documentation:

> records must be accepted as org.apache.flink.table.data.RowData. The
> framework provides runtime converters such that a sink can still work
> on common data structures and perform a conversion at the beginning.

The goal here is to keep the Row data structure and only convert Row into RowData when inserted into the SinkFunction. So in this way the rest of the code does not need to be changed.

```
class MySinkFunction(outputFormat: MyOutputFormat) extends RichSinkFunction[RowData] with CheckpointedFunction
```

So the resulting question is: How to convert RowData into Row when using a DynamicTableSink and OutputFormat? Where should the conversion happen?

links:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/sourceSinks.html
https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/connector/jdbc

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a converter instance in the `Context` provided in `org.apache.flink.table.connector.sink.DynamicTableSink#getSinkRuntimeProvider`.

```
    // create type information for the DeserializationSchema
    final TypeInformation<RowData> producedTypeInfo =
            context.createTypeInformation(producedDataType);

    // most of the code in DeserializationSchema will not work on internal data structures
    // create a converter for conversion at the end
    final DataStructureConverter converter =
            context.createDataStructureConverter(producedDataType);
```

The instance is Java serializable and can be passed into the sink function. You should also call the `converter.open()` method in your sink function.

A more complex example can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-table/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/examples/java/connectors/ChangelogSocketExample.java) (for sources but sinks work in a similar way). Have a look at `SocketDynamicTableSource` and `ChangelogCsvFormat` in the same package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at this.

Comment: The question is if we even need to implement a serialization schema for a db sink, like one for postgres or vertica.

Comment: No, most connectors might not need a format. The example just shows the full story because many people also like to implement only a custom formats. But the concept is the same.